# Asynchronous execution order of multiple function each one depending on the last one

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I really have hard time understanding asynchronous code, and callback function.

I want to make a sequence of function that depend on the result of the last one. The first function will import data from a data base.

import value > fctOne(Value) > fctTwo(value of fctOne(Value)) > fctThree(value of fctTwo(value)) > and so on ...

App.js will need to wait for value to be imported, so fctOne can't be synchronous. But then will all my functions behind it will need to be asynchronous too ? They have to run in order.

My failing code : with error : "callBack(result) TypeError: callBack is not a function"

DB.JSON

```
{"val":5,"square":25,"SquareRoot":5,"dividedByHimself":1}
```

on app.js

```
const db = require('./DB.json')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const dbPath = path.join(__dirname,'DB.json')
let data = fs.readFileSync(dbPath)
let userDBupdate = JSON.parse(data)


///function to import data with simulation of the delay to obtain imported value//
const value = (pathDB,callBack) => {
 setTimeout((err) => {
   if(err){
     return callBack(new Error("loading failed"))
   }
   const val = db[pathDB]
   callBack(val)
 }, 500)
}
//// square function 
let square = (pathDB, callBack) => {
 value(pathDB, (val) => {
   let result = val * val
   userDBupdate.square = result
   callBack(result)
   let dataMAJ = JSON.stringify(userDBupdate)
   fs.writeFileSync(dbPath, dataMAJ)
 })
}
square('val')

let squareRootOfSquare = (pathDB, callBack) => {
 square(pathDB, (val) => {
   let result = Math.sqrt(val)
   userDBupdate.square = result
   callBack(result)
   let dataMAJ = JSON.stringify(userDBupdate)
   fs.writeFileSync(dbPath, dataMAJ)
 })

}
squareRootOfSquare('val')
```

Comment: What exactly is failing? Are you getting error messages? Not the expected result?

Comment: What you really want for sequential asynchronous operations is to make them all work with promises and then use `await`.  The coding for the logic flow and for error handling will end up a lot, lot simpler and this is the present and future of asynchronous coding in Javascript.

Comment: @Bergi sorry i will update the post with the error

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for your answer i will try to rewrite the code using async await, but isn't it just a simpler way to write the same thing ? Here i was trying to understand how to to use callbacks for sequential synchronous operations.

Comment: Yes, simpler way to accomplish your goal.  That is the whole point.  That's why it was invented.  Trust me - you really don't want to be trying to coordinate multiple asynchronous operations with callbacks.  Your error handling alone is a nightmare.  This is entirely why both promises and `async/await` were invented.  The moment I encounter an asynchronous operation or library that doesn't support promises, I immediately promisify it (or switch to an alternative that does support promises) and only EVER write asynchronous code using promises.

Comment: `squareRootOfSquare` expects two arguments but you are calling it with one.

Answer (score 0):

As jfriend00 mentioned is tried to rewrite it using promise. And yes for serial calculation it's way more easier and cleaner.

```
const valuePromise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(()=> {
    const val = db.val
    resolve(val)
  })
}).then(function(resultOfCall){
  let resultSquare = resultOfCall * resultOfCall
    userDBupdate.square = resultSquare
    let dataMAJ = JSON.stringify(userDBupdate)
    fs.writeFileSync(dbPath, dataMAJ)
  return resultSquare
}).then(function(resultOfSquare){
  let resultRoot = Math.sqrt(resultOfSquare)
  userDBupdate.squareRootOfSquare = resultRoot
  let dataMAJ = JSON.stringify(userDBupdate)
  fs.writeFileSync(dbPath, dataMAJ)
  return resultRoot
}).then(function(resultOfSquareRoot){
  let resultOfDivide = resultOfSquareRoot / resultOfSquareRoot
  userDBupdate.squareRoot = resultOfDivide
  let dataMAJ = JSON.stringify(userDBupdate)
  fs.writeFileSync(dbPath, dataMAJ)
  return resultOfDivide
})
```